Concat a few columns from a query
In Google Spreadsheet, I have a query:
=QUERY({dataset1, dataset2}, "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 WHERE ...");

This outputs 4 columns. I'd like to concatenate Col2 and Col3 (only) such as the output is: Col1, Col2 + " " + Col3, Col4
I found How to use CONCAT in QUERY? and related blogs that all explain how to concatenate all columns with a double transpose, but this isn't what I need. I want to choose the subset of columns I want to concatenate (without modifying any of the original datasets). Trying to do this without an Apps Script either...

What RDBMS are you querying against? That information is necessary so that we know the features it supports.

The datasets are just other sheets in the spreadsheet. E.g. sheet1!A:Z

We would have known that if you had provided actual SQL instead of incomplete (missing a FROM and the WHERE). In the future, please remember that the only information we have available to us to use to answer the question is the information you provide in your post. Typically, posts that fail to include those specifics get downvoted and closed as needing details or focus or as missing a [mre].

You can't do this with QUERY. You will have to manually create the array.
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
   data, {dataset1, dataset2},
   {INDEX(data,,1), INDEX(data,,2)&" "&INDEX(data,,3), INDEX(data,,4)}))


I need QUERY somewhere in there to apply WHERE/GROUP_BY clauses and do some reduction operations.
Using your formula, I can get it to work with query:
=ArrayFormula(Let(data, {Query({dataset1, dataset2}, "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 WHERE ...",1)},  {INDEX(data,,1), INDEX(data,,2)&" "&INDEX(data,,3), INDEX(data,,4) }))
Now one last hurdle, I want to specify/customize the name of the concatenated column (as I would be able to if this was supported with QUERY). Right now, I get "first name last name" as a column name, I'd like to rename that column "full name".
